# javascript regex replace, how to provide regex condition (and flags) as variable instead of inline?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Using the JS replace function with regex, and will have dozens of replace statements.

```
var NewHTML = OriginalHTML
.replace(/\bJavaScript\b/gi, "<a href=\"http://js.com/\">$&</a>")
.replace(/\bMySQL\b/gi, "<a href=\"http://www.mysql.com/\">$&</a>")
;
```

To make it more readable and more manageable (i.e. easier to change the regex pattern or flags by changing it in one place instead of on every line), trying to pull the replace regex condition and replace flags out into a separate variable:

```
var pattern = /\b(?!\-)(?!\/)\b(?!\-)/gi;

var NewHTML = OriginalHTML
.replace("JavaScript", "<a href=\"http://js.com/\">$&</a>", pattern)
.replace("MySQL", "<a href=\"http://www.mysql.com/\">$&</a>", pattern)
```

Problem is, the inline call is being completely ignored... both the regex portion and the flags portion.

Can anyone spot what's wrong with the JS replace call or declaration of the regex/flags variable? :-)

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what it is you're trying to change, or why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a lookup object to map the originals to URLs:

```
// Original string
var o = "MySql is a DBMS, whereas javascript is a client side scripting language";

//Patterns
var patterns = {
    "javascript": "http://js.com/",
    "mysql": "http://www.mysql.com/"
};

//Constructing regex
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
};
var keys = [];
for (i in patterns) {
    if (patterns.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        keys.push(RegExp.escape(i));
    }
}
var pattern = new RegExp("\\b(" + keys.join("|") + ")\\b", "gi");

//Replace
var n = o.replace(pattern, function(m, g1) {
    return "<a href='" + patterns[g1.toLowerCase()] + "'>" + g1 + "< /a>";
});
console.log(n);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/qP9Er/

---

EDIT:

As per your request, here is a version that replaces the first n occurrences. You can find a demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rGwZb/):

```
// Original string
var o = '<p>Test 1 (JavaScript - <strong>1st keyword instance to be replaced</strong>): <br><a href="http://js1.net">Link to JavaScript site (existing URL)</a> is a scripting language commonly implemented as part of a web browser in order to create enhanced user interfaces and dynamic websites. JavaScript is very flexible.</p><p>more text here... and another mention of JavaScript. also javascript and JAVAScrIPT <br><br></p><p>Test 2 (MySQL - <strong>1st keyword instance to be replaced</strong>): <br><a href="http://www.mysql.com">MySQL</a>  (existing URL) is the most popular open-source database system.</p> <p><a href="http://www.themysqllink.com">link to a MySQL site</a> (existing URL).</p><p> More stuff about Mysql, also mysql and mySQL</p>';

//Patterns
var patterns = {
    "javascript": "http://js.com/",
    "mysql": "http://www.mysql.com/",
    "mention": "http://www.x.com/"
};

//Number of replacements
var num = 1;

//Constructing regex
RegExp.escape = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
var keys = [];
for (key in patterns) {
    if (patterns.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(RegExp.escape(key));
    }
}
var regexen = [];
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    regexen[i] = new RegExp("\\b(" + keys[i] + ")\\b(?![^<]*?<\/a>)", "i");
}

//Replace
for (var i = 0; i < regexen.length; i++) {
    var count = 0;
    var pattern = regexen[i];
    while (count < num) {
        o = o.replace(pattern, function(m, g1) {
            return "<a href='" + patterns[g1.toLowerCase()] + "'>" + g1 + "</a>";
        });
        count++;
    }
}
document.write(o);
```

Comment: agreed, this approach is very clean, much more manageable, thank you.But it's not working for me? here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dbaritchi/AD5TU/ -- Thx!!

Comment: @Dan I made a couple mistakes, I'm debugging them now. Will update my answer.

Comment: awesome, thanks SO much, this works perfectly and is far more elegant and maintainable! :-)

Comment: @Dan Just a note, I've updated the answer so that regex special characters in keys are escaped. Without this, the code would break if you had strings like `C++`, `A*` etc.

Comment: @Asad ran into an odd issue with a larger test data set... If you update the "pattern" variable to remove the "g" flag (so only the 1st instance is replaced), then all the replacing stops except the 1st instance of the 1st keyword. What do you think? Here's the JSFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/dbaritchi/qP9Er/8/ * Just a thought, would it be easier to leave the "g" flag set but somehow have the function only do x number of replacements max, i.e. "2"? *

Comment: Thanks @Asad. Correction from post above, last sentence: "* Just a thought, would it be easier to leave the "g" flag set but somehow have the function only do x number of replacements FOR EACH KEYWORD on the page max, i.e. "2"? *"

Comment: @Dan I can't quite follow your fiddle. The uncommented line still includes the `g` flag. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Asad sorry, left the "g" for continuity. delete that one letter and hit "run" to see the behavior I'm talking about...

Comment: @Dan Yes, it only replaces the first occurrence of any key in the string. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @Asad sure, that's the thing, wasn't immediately obvious, but only the 1st instance of the FIRST keyword is replaced if you remove the "g". Here's the more clear example with an updated jsfiddle. :-) -- http://jsfiddle.net/dbaritchi/qP9Er/9/ ("g" already removed here)

Comment: @Dan Right, I know. Exactly one replacement to the string occurs, which is what happens when a regex is not global. What would you like it to do instead?

Comment: @Asad sure, exactly one replacement for the particular string, i.e. "mysql". But we're specifying a table of different strings (mysql, javascript, etc.), so the goal would be to do one replacement for each of the strings found. Does that make sense? Thanks! LOL sure would be nice if regex provided a way to specify a more precise replacement level, i.e. 1 replacement vs. global (all) replacement vs. x number of replacements. :-)

Comment: @Dan I've updated the answer with a version that replaces the first n occurrences of each key.

Answer (score 2):

The `.replace()` function only takes 2 arguments.

You can build a regex dynamically by building it as a string and then passing it to the `RegExp()` constructor.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong about the replace params: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

But you are right about the use of RegExp constructor.

Comment: @GabrielGartz that's Firefox-only as far as I know.  The standard only has 2 arguments. And in any case he's passing the pattern as the third argument, which even in Firefox won't work.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the reply. I'm confused, thought it took three arguments? See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace at the top, and the example of this further down, screenshot: http://www.screencast.com/t/5PhceR0RhF

Comment: @Dan see where it says "Non-standard"?  That usually should be read as, "DO NOT USE" :=)  In any case, you're passing the regexp object, while what that parameter should be is a string containing the flags. That documentation page is badly worded; I'll fix it.

Comment: @Pointy you are wrong again dude, that specification was made in Javascript 1.2 / ECMAScript 3 standart, that is accept by any moddern browser. The prototypes from ECMAScript 6 that almost only works in mozzila, because they are still in draft work.

Comment: @Pointy ugh, it does say non-standard, and very clearly at that lol. Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielGartz I'm looking at the 2011 ECMA-262 edition 5.1 (Rev 6) and the `replace()` function is specified as having 2 arguments, "searchValue" and "replaceValue". The Microsoft browsers don't seem to support a third argument, according to MSDN, even IE10 (which has to be accepted as a "modern" browser).

Comment: @GabrielGartz also the EcmaScript 3rd Edition from 1999 has `replace()` with only 2 parameters, section 15.5.4.11.

Answer (score 1):

The flags parameter is [nonstandard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  And more importantly, it only tags flags such as "gi" and not a whole regular expression.

I would write a loop to deal with the duplication.  Or have a function create the String so I can keep it in once place.